# Protractor randomly fails after onPrepare

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

The issue that I am running into occurs completely randomly both locally and on a Selenium Grid.

What happens is certain specs will just randomly fail after the onPrepare.
The command prompt gives this information.

> currentRunnable().addExpectationResult(false, {
>                          ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExpectationResult' of undefined
>       at Env.fail (c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
>   r\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:894
>   :24)

and

> From: Task: WebDriver.manage().window().maximize()
>       at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (c:\Users\User\AppDat
>   a\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdri
>   ver\webdriver.js:360:15)

The onPrepare runs the command

`browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Immediately followed by a spec that runs before every spec interacts with non-angular elements that logs in and navigates to the application.

The error occurs and immediately stops the test and fails, but it does not report anything with jasmine, using jasmine2-html-reporter, and will move on to the next test.

I can run the exact same command immediately afterwards and there will be no errors at all. It does not frequently happen on any specific spec.

Has anybody encountered anything similar?

Comment: Is it the only code which causes the issue? `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();` I mean, if you remove it, it runs ok? What is the minimal setup (code) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It normally runs okay, it is just a fluke occurrence maybe 1 or 2 out of every 50 specs will fail. The maximize is necessary because the application is not responsive and needs to be a certain size.

Comment: Seems like there is an issue in your conf.js file. Could you share it and update in your question?